# Stop Microsoft Git Provider in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2013

I have some projects to work on that involve a grotesquely large csproj that is the COTS CMS application I'm extending. The project has over 16k files in it which is ridiculous but it's not something I can control, nor can I control the choice of CMS platforms. The project is in a solution... the solution is in a git repository.

With a project that large, using the source control plugin in Visual Studio 2013 means any change to a file and subsequent save results in my CPU and RAM usage spiking to a ridiculous percentage for several minutes, making the fan spin on high constantly all day and making my IDE laggy. I have a very high-end desktop replacement laptop and I'm certain throwing hardware at the problem won't make it go away. So, I go into options and set the source control provider to None... problem solved after a couple-minute lockup while VS does something.

Now for the problem... when I come in the next day and open up the solution, the plugin selection is back on Microsoft Git Provider. Is there a setting or something I can configure to tell Visual Studio (**ideally for just this solution or project**) to stop trying to use the integrated source control?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem; if someone has suggestions , I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I need  the Work Items from TFS but I use git-tfs to manage my projects locally.

I managed to disable the built-in Visual  Studio Git Provider by deleting all occurrences of those registry keys:

`7FE30A77-37F9-4CF2-83DD-96B207028E1B`

`11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8`

Comment: Seems like every time you install a Visual Studio update you'll probably have to delete the registry keys again.